# Bourbaki theory of set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In Chapter 2 section 1 subsection 5 of Bourbaki's "Theory of sets" there is this remark

$$\exists z(z\in \left\{x,y\right\} \wedge R\left\{z\right\})\Leftrightarrow R\left\{x\right\}\vee R\left\{y\right\}$$

Whereas this equivalence is perfectly clear, I could not deduced it from previous theorems in the book. Can someone provide a clear proof with theorems strictly from the Bourbaki book?

Note: I believe the original Boubaki text is "incorrect"; the equivalence it actually refers to is

$$\exists z(z\in \left\{x,y\right\} \wedge R\left\{z\right\})\Leftrightarrow (R\left\{x\right\}\vee R\left\{y\right\}) \wedge z\in \left\{x,y\right\}$$

or

$$z\in \left\{x,y\right\} \Rightarrow  \exists zR\left\{z\right\}\Leftrightarrow R\left\{x\right\}\vee R\left\{y\right\} $$

Comment: Why are you reading Bourbaki's set theory ? There are many better books on set theory.

Comment: I am not using Boubaki's book for learning but am interested in the approach the Boubaki group used to "organize" mathematical knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical theorems used are [see [page 69](https://books.google.it/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&pg=PA69)] :

> C32. $\exists x \ (R \lor S) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x R \lor \exists x S), \ \  \forall x \ (R \land S) \Leftrightarrow (\forall x R \land \forall x S)$
>
> C33. $\forall x \ (R \lor S)\Leftrightarrow (R \lor \forall x \ S), \ \ \forall x \ (R \lor S) \Leftrightarrow (R \lor \forall x S)$, if $x$ is not *free* in $R$,

and the properties of *equality* [page 44] :

> S6. $(t=u) \to (R(t) \Leftrightarrow R(u))$,

and [page 46] : $x=x$.

From S6 we have, obviously : $((t=u) \land R(t)) \Rightarrow R(u)$.

Thus, from :

> $\exists z \ [(z \in \{ x, y \}) \land R(z)]$

replacing $z \in \{ x, y \}$ with $z=x \lor z=y$, we get, using C32 :

> $\exists z \ [(z=x \lor z=y) \land R(z)] \Leftrightarrow \exists z \ (z=x \land R(z)) \lor \exists z \ (z=y \land R(z)).$

By equality, this amounts to :

> $\exists z \ R(x) \lor \exists z \ R(y).$

But $z$ is not free in $R(x)$, and thus it amounts to :

> > $R(x) \lor R(y).$

---

Similar for : $\forall z \ [(z \in \{ x, y \}) \to R(z)]$.

Replacing $z \in \{ x, y \}$ with $z=x \lor z=y$ and distributing, we get, using C32 :

> $\forall z \ (z=x \to Rz) \land \forall z \ (z=y \to Rz)$.

Instantiating both universal quantifiers (and some tautological transformations) we have :

> $(x=x \to Rx) \land (y=y \to Ry)$.

By equality : $x=x$ and $y=y$ we finally get :

> > $Rx \land Ry$.

Comment: Hi Mauro thanks for the reply but I have done the exactly reasoning but found it to be "faulty" the problem happens in this step: $$∃z [(z=x∨z=y)∧R(z)]⇔∃z (z=x∧R(z))∨∃z (z=y∧R(z)).$$ to $$∃z R(x)∨∃z R(y).$$ so $$∃z (z=x∧R(z))∨∃z (z=y∧R(z))$$ implies $$∃z R(x)∨∃z R(y)$$ but not the other way around; so it is not an equivalence. To be precise $$∃z (z=x∧R(z))∨∃z (z=y∧R(z))$$ is equivalent to $$∃z (z=x∧R(x))∨∃z (z=y∧R(y))$$ and then to $$(z=x∧ ∃zR(x)) ∨ (z=y∧ ∃zR(y))$$ thus finally to $$(z=x∨z=y)∧(z=x∨R(y))∧(R(x)∨z=y)∧(R(x)∨R(y))$$

Comment: the key point is that, $$((t=u)∧R(t))⇒R(u)$$ follows from axiom but $$R(u)⇒((t=u)∧R(t))$$ does not.

Comment: @LuminiaQs - I do not agree: Start with $Rx$ and (by axiom for equality) get: $(x=x) \land Rx$. Then, by $\exists$-intro: $\exists z \ (z=x \land Rz)$.

Comment: Hi Mauro, you are absolutely right :). When I first read though the remark I couldn't explicate all the details and wondered why something seemed so obvious could be so difficult, at times, to write down in a proof. I actually thought out the proof while I was writing the question but was nonetheless interested in how people would respond to the question and Bourbaki in general. Thanks for the answer.